# How to Generate Serial No in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
grvResults.DataSource = Infoware.StudentModules
        .Where(x => x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo && x.Status != "Pending")
        .Select(x => new NewResults { 
                                       SlNo = ---, 
                                       ModuleCode = x.ModuleCode, 
                                       ModuleDescription = x.Module.ModuleDescription, 
                                       Score = x.Score, 
                                       Status = x.Status })
         .ToList();
```

Here I have gridview with autogenerated columns and I need to Generate
Serial No.

What should I write here "SlNo = ---" in lambda expression in order to generate serial no.

Comment: Possible expression you should write totally depends on how your desired serial number should look like. It's impossible to suggest more until you'll provide more details.

Comment: We can't guess what kind of serial number you want to generate. Or are you simply asking how to create an incrementing value?

Comment: I just need to generate Row Number for Gridview. here this code generates 5 lines, I just need a row number for each row starting with 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) other overload which gives index as well:

```
.Select((x,index) => new NewResults { 
                                       SlNo = index, 
                                       ModuleCode = x.ModuleCode, 
                                       ModuleDescription = x.Module.ModuleDescription, 
                                       Score = x.Score, 
                                       Status = x.Status })
```

if you want it to start from 1 then:

```
.Select((x,index) => new NewResults { 
                                           SlNo = ++index, 
                                           ModuleCode = x.ModuleCode, 
                                           ModuleDescription = x.Module.ModuleDescription, 
                                           Score = x.Score, 
                                           Status = x.Status })
```

Comment: what is select here, is it a local variable ??

Comment: Select is extension method for IEnumerable available in .Net Framework, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: grvResults.DataSource = Infoware.StudentModules.Where(x => x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo && x.Status != "Pending").Select((x,index) => new NewResults { SlNo = index , ModuleCode = x.ModuleCode, ModuleDescription = x.Module.ModuleDescription, Score = x.Score, Status = x.Status }).ToList();  **This is my final Expression and I got an error.**

Comment: got an error does not help, what's the error specifically?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[NewResults] Select[StudentModule,NewResults](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[InfowareModel.StudentModule], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[InfowareModel.StudentModule,System.Int32,NewResults]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: ok, you are using LInq to Entities then you will need to load results in memory first like :``.Where(x => x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo && x.Status != "Pending").AsEnumerable()``

Comment: Thanks alot, This is working fine but its very slow. what can be done to decrease the loading time..

Comment: what are the number of records coming?

Comment: No of Records are just 20 but still its taking 5 seconds to populate the grid, when I am removing the slno its taking no time to populate the grid.

Comment: Is there any method to generate Serial no to gridview which has AutoGenerateColumns property set to true.

Comment: there are ways , see :https://www.google.com.pk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asp.net%20generate%20serial%20no%20for%20rows